# Formatting and grammar of sponsoring scientist statement

Tags: mathematics, postdocs, nsf, mentoring

Is there a formatting guide for the Sponsoring Scientist Statement for NSF postdocs in the Department of Mathematical Sciences? All I'm finding is [this two page document](https://www.nsf.gov/mps/dms/MSPRF/MSPRF_fastlane_instructions_host_institutions.pdf), which is much less precise than the usual NSF rules.

Here is a particular thing which I can't find out: The NSF has a rule that Project Summaries should be in the third person ("the PI", not "I").
 Should I likewise write "the sponsoring scientist" rather than "I"? Should I write "the PI" rather than using his or her name?

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer, but:

- I suggest you ask colleagues of yours who have been sponsoring scientists, or who have been sponsored by others, for copies of their sponsoring scientist statements. Then you could just immitate the format
- Ask the people at the NSF to whom you (or whoever) is supposed to submit that statement - either for formatting guidelines or a "will this format be ok?" question.